# How do I create nested repositories in GitHub?

Tags: git, github, repository, git-submodules

I am able to create a repository via https://github.com/ (say `repo`) and have:

```
https://github.com/username/repo.git
```

How do I create another repository (say `sub_repo`) placed under `repo` and expectedly have:

```
https://github.com/username/repo/sub_repo.git
```

Comment: This [app](https://github.com/ingydotnet/git-subrepo) could also help to manage sub-repo as a Git Submodule Alternative

Answer (score 34, accepted):

GitHub does not allow nested repositories (IIRC Git doesn't allow this for bare repositories).

However, you can use submodules to nest repositories on the "client side" in the working tree.

You need to clone the parent directory.

Then, add the sub-repository as a [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules):

```
git submodule add https://github.com/username/sub_repo.git
```

The sub_repo module will then be linked to the parent repo and can be found in the sub_repo directory.

Commit (.gitmodules and sub_repo), push and you're done.

Comment: How do I create `username/repo/sub-repo.git` instead of `username/sub-repo.git`? My purpose is to well organize my codes.

Comment: Sorry, fixed a typo. A sub_repo is a normal repository - threre is no way to use nested folders on github.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve this with Git Subtree?

Comment: No, subtree means that the files/commits of another repository are directly integrated in a new one.

Answer (score 4):

github does not support nesting repositories. If you don't want to have absolute urls for submodules the custom is to place them next to super-repository and use "../" in urls, like here: https://github.com/losalamos/cinch-nested-example/blob/d59c26a89153148ba29d68dd5ee455a88efbc9a2/.gitmodules