# Does gitorious or even git support on sub-repo below a repo of a project?

Tags: git, gitorious

I have a project with structure for example

- Internet>App1>SMTPClient
- Internet>App1>MailFormInput

So I created a project called "`Internet`" and repo "`App1`". I am able to create the first repo as "`SMTPClient`" and no more option even as admin is available for me to create a new repo.

... Or am I heading in a wrong direction after all?

Comment: Answer to similar question about github: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35053579/2303202 . I think it should apply to most hostings

Answer (score 1):

Git does support it, but as a reference: a **[submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)** (one repo references a second repo).

As for Gitorious, since it [has been acquired by GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/2015/03/03/gitlab-acquires-gitorious/) over a year ago, it would be easier to upgrade/install GitLab

Or at least, it would be best to create the project `App1` (instead of `Internet`), and create two repos in `App1`.